# Linked List issue - Why is it adding a 0 as a element to my list when the user types in 'N to quit adding more elements?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

So I working on creating a function called 'Create' that asks the user to enter numbers for a linked list. If the user types in 'Y', then ask to enter another element else if the user types 'N' stop and display the linked list, but I am having a bit of trouble. When I run it, it doesn't give me the option to type in Y or N and also when I type in N, it adds a 0 to the linked list. What is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//-------------------------------------------------
struct node {
int data;
struct node *next;
}*start=NULL;
//------------------------------------------------------------

void create() {
char ch;
do {

struct node *new_node,*current;
new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

printf("Enter the data : ");
scanf("%d",&new_node->data);
new_node->next=NULL;

if(start==NULL) {
  start=new_node;
  current=new_node;
} else {
  current->next=new_node;
  current=new_node;
}

printf("Do you want to create another?(Y\N) ");
ch = getchar();
  } while(ch!='N');
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------

void display()  {
  struct node *new_node;
  printf("The Linked List : ");
  new_node=start;

  while(new_node!=NULL) {
    printf("%d--->",new_node->data);
    new_node=new_node->next;
  }
  printf("NULL\n");
}
//----------------------------------------------------

int main() {

  create();
 display();
}
```

Comment: The `scanf` will leave a newline character in the input which the `getchar` will read.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getchar not taken in consideration after scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828370/getchar-not-taken-in-consideration-after-scanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- move the declaration of `struct node *new_node, *current;` to outside the `do` loop (to just before the do), because you want them to keep their values between iterations.

2-  a newline character remained in the buffer after the scanf that read the number, because the user had to type *return* after the number, and the scanf did not consume it. To skip this newline when getting the Y/N answer, get your Y/N answer in this way instead of `ch = getchar();`:

```
  scanf(" %c", &ch); // notice the blank before the %c, important to skip the newline that remained in the buffer
```

3- although not necessary, better avoid using the escape character `\` in your question, use "Y/N" instead of "Y\N"

Your code worked perfectly after I made these modifications.